# Making a scheduled method Thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-safety, synchronized

I have a method that is invoked by a scheduler every minute to get a file from ftp, process and persists its records to a DB. I need to make this thread safe so that if the method has to perform multiple files at once, it acts a in a thread safe way..

```
public synchronized void processData(String data){
   //do processing
}
```

is this really going to be a thread safe method that will handle high volumes of load gracefully?

Comment: in my scenario, lets imagine the scheduler is invoked at 11:00 which gets 1000 files to process in the processData method. The scheduler is configured to kick in every 1 minute and it gets invoked again in 11:01 but the processing of the initial 1000 files is not completed. What will be the best way to address this scenario? 
1. eliminate synchronized keyword in method
2.start a new thread for each file process 
?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's thread-safe as long as it doesn't use any stateful fields from the enclosing object.

In other words, if there is a class-level field that is manipulated or accessed in `processData(String data)` with the intention of keeping track of what's going on, then it's not thread-safe.

An example might be a class-level field called `private Boolean hasConnection;`  If you need to check whether or not a connection exists with this field, then you don't have a thread-safe method.

If you meet this requirement, then you don't even have to add the `synchronized` keyword to your method.  It will be, by default, thread-safe, and an unlimited number of threads may access it simultaneously.

If you do not meet this requirement, then you will need to post the whole class in order to determine whether or not it is thread-safe.

Comment: Isn't synchronized on the method level using the Object instance for a lock? Meaning, all the instance level fields are protected...

Comment: @rfeak they're not necessarily protected at all. If they're `public`, they're definitely not protected.  If they're `private` but accessed by non-`synchronized` methods, they're also not protected.

Comment: I guess protected is the wrong way to put it. Synchronized on the method uses the object for the lock. Meaning that the variables in the object instance cannot be accessed by multiple threads at the same time, for THAT method (or any other method marked synchronized on that class). My point being that you CAN use instance variables from inside that method, as long as you mark other methods synchronized that might change the state.

Comment: @rfeak "as long as you mark other methods synchronized that might change the state" - That's exactly why I stated "If you do not meet this requirement, then you will need to post the whole class in order to determine whether or not it is thread-safe."  If the other relevant methods do not synchronize around `this` (via a lock or synchronized methods) then the code in `public synchronized processData(String data) {...}` might not be thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the mysterious "process the file" operation is self-contained, the biggest thing you should worry about is your DB connection: do not make it shared, obtain a new one each time from a connection string, and use a [connection pool](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html). Do not make your method synchronized, unless you need to access shared state inside your class; otherwise, your method would not be able to make progress concurrently on multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Please describe us what resources your method uses, and which of those resources are shared.

If you do not use common object, there is no problem.

If you do use common resources, you need to make sure these resources can be accessed in a thread-safe manner, or are not accessed by multiple threads.

Your question is about performance. In general, `processData` seems to be a method which will take some time to complete: you are using databases. The time required to get a lock is minimal compared to a DB Query. So no, the `synchronized` keyword will not give you any noticeable performance impact.